# Remote port forwarding | SSH

Tags: python, ssh, remote-server

I've encountered a minor issue when I am doing remote port forwarding.

I am trying to establish connection like the following:

```
ssh -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000 user@server
```

This currently works and I have no issues doing `python manage.py runserver`.

However when I exit and I want to re-establish the connection in order to command `runserver` I will have to run the same command.

I am therefore wondering if there is a way to access with `ssh user@server` and still be able to use certain ports without doing the full command.

Extra notes: I am running windows

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an alias for an ssh connection by creating/editing ~/.ssh/config file. When you create the file, you can define a connection something like:

```
Host dev
    HostName dev.example.com
    User john
    Port 2322
```

then subsequently you can use: `ssh dev`

See: https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/

I haven't specifically tested port forwarding, but if you look at the man page for ssh_config, there appear to be port forwarding options which can be configured in the config file:

https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5

I use ~/.ssh/config to configure ssh aliases using python and the Git for Windows SSH client on Windows, however, it may depend on how you have configured your ssh client.